# How to register an Android device to a push channel with parse.com

Tags: android, push-notification, parse-platform, google-cloud-messaging

I use parse.com to send push notifications.

I register my device like this in my application class:

```
Parse.initialize(this, "appId","clientKey");
PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MainActivity.class);
PushService.subscribe(this, "newShirt", MainActivity.class);
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
```

But in the dashboard no registration for this channel shows up and push notifications sent to this channel are not received.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I found my problem.

Capital letters seem to not work as channels with parse. 
I changed my code like this and it is working like a charm:

```
Parse.initialize(this, "appId","clientKey");
PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MainActivity.class);
PushService.subscribe(this, "newshirt", MainActivity.class);
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
```